# Exercise 10.J of The elements of integration and Lebesgue measure Bartle's book

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The part of the problem is the next.

Let (X,***X***,$\mu$) be the measure space on the natural numbers X=$\mathbb{N}$ with the counting measure defined on all subsets of X=$\mathbb{N}$. Let (Y,***Y***,$\nu$) be an arbitrary measure space.

Show that a set **E** in Z= X $\times$ Y belongs ***Z= X $\times$ Y*** if only if each section $E_{n}$ of **E** belongs to ***Y***.

I can proof in the this $\Rightarrow$ direction, but I have problems with this $\Leftarrow$ direction, so I think that for this part I need to use the measure space (X,***X***,$\mu$).

Could you please give some suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that for the counting measure on $X=\mathbb{N}$ the $\sigma$-algebra is $\textbf{X}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. So, if each section $E_n$ belongs to $\mathbb{Y}$, we have that the set $\{n\}\times E_n\in \textbf{Z}=\textbf{X}\times\textbf{Y}$, and $$E=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(\{n\}\times E_n)$$ belongs to $\textbf{Z}$ because it is a countable union of elements in $\textbf{Z}$.