# Second part pf the exercise 10.J of the elements of integration and Lebesgue of bartle's book

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let (X,**X**,$\mu$) be the measure space on the natural numbers X=$\mathbb{N}$ with the counting measure defined on all subsets of X=$\mathbb{N}$. Let (Y,**Y**,$\nu$) be an arbitrary measure space.

A function *f* on *Z=X$\times$ Y* to $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable if only if each section *f$_{n}$* is **Y**-measurable. Moreover, *f* is integrable with respect to $\pi$ if only if the series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{Y}|f_n|d\nu$

is convergent.

I have problem with this $\Leftarrow$ direction.

I need to prove that the set $\{(x,y)\in X\times Y: f(x,y)>\alpha\}\in$ **X$\times$ Y**.

But, by hypothesis I know that the set $\{y\in Y: f_n(y)>\alpha\}\in$ **Y**.

My idea is the next, the set $\{(x,y)\in X\times Y: f(x,y)>\alpha\}$ must be equal to $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(A\times \{y\in Y: f_n(y)>\alpha\})$, but I can't found the form of the set A.

The second part, in this $\Rightarrow$ direction I know that the function |*f$_n$*|=*f$_n$*$^+$ + *f$_n$*$^-$, thus $\int |f_n|=\int f_n^+ + \int f_n^-$.
And I'm not sure if *f* is integrable then f$_n$ is integreable, 
in that case, I have the result that I need. And in this $\Leftarrow$ direction I can't relate the convergence of the serie with the integral of *f*

Could you give me a suggestion?

Comment: Wouldn't it be $\{(x,y) \in X \times Y : f(x,y) > \alpha\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (\{n\} \times \{y \in Y : f_n(y) > \alpha\})$?

Comment: I thought the same thing but I wasn't sure

Comment: For the second part, try defining $g_n(x,y) = \delta(n,x)|f_n(y)|$, where $$\delta(n,x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if }x = n \\ 0 & \text{ if } x \neq n \\ \end{cases}$$ Then $\sum_{n=1}^{N}g_n(x,y)$ increases monotonically to $|f(x,y)|$ as $N \to \infty$, so the monotone convergence theorem applies.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 10J asks many things of us. Other Math Stack Exchange posts [such as this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1756857/1015934), focus only in one of the aspects of the problem. I will prove all of them for the sake of completeness.

**Part I:** $E\in X\times Y$ is measurable if and only if $E_n$ is measurable in $Y$.

**Proof:**
$(\Rightarrow )$ This holds for general spaces and Bartles proves it in Lemma 10.6. However, let me prove it again, because Bartle omits a couple of steps.

Let $\mathcal{R}$ denote the set of all sets in the cartesian product, such that $E_n$ is measurable. Clearly, if $\dot{\cup}_{i=1}^n A_{i}\times B_i$ is a general element in $Z_o$ which is finite union of measurable rectangles:

$$(\dot{\cup}_{i=1}^n A_{i}\times B_i)_x=\cup_{i| x\in A_i}B_i$$

Finite union of measurable sets is measurable in $Y$. But this means that $Z_o\subset \mathcal{R}$. Furthermore $ \mathcal{R}$ is a sigma algebra because if $R_i\in \mathcal{R}$, we have that $(\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} R_i)_x=\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} (R_i)_x$ which is measurable, so $\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} R_i\in \mathcal{R}$. Similarly, if $R_i \in \mathcal{R}$, we have $(R_i^C)_x=({R_i}_x)^C$ to be measurable hence $ R_i \in \mathcal{R}$. Therefore, $\mathcal{R}$ is a sigma algebra containing $Z_o$ and $\textbf{Z}=\sigma(Z_o)\subset \mathcal{R}$

$(\Leftarrow)$  It holds that $E=\cup_{n=1}^\infty \{n\}\times E_n$. Each $\{n\}\times E_n$ is a measurable rectangle by our hypothesis and therefore, countable union of them is certainly measurable.

**Part II:** There is a unique product measure $\pi$ such that it satisfies:

$$ \pi(E)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E_n)$$

**Proof:** Theorem 10.4 from Bartle establishes (as a consequence of the monotone convergence theorem and Caratheodory), that there is a measure $\pi$ such that $\pi(A\times B)=\mu(A)\nu(B)$, if $A\times B\in Z_o$. However, for any general $E\in \textbf{Z}$, because of part I, we have $E_n$ to be measurable. Hence:

$$\pi(E)=\pi(\dot{\cup}_{n=1}^\infty \{n\}\times E_n )=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \pi(\{n\}\times E_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu (E_n)$$

But this establishes the uniqueness part and also the formula to compute $\pi$ in any given set.

**Part III:** A function $f:X\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable if and only if we have $f_n(y)=f(n,y)$ measurable as a function from $Y$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

**Proof:** Let $O$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.

$(\Rightarrow)$  $f_n^{-1}(O)=\{y|f(n,y)\in O \}=\{y| (n,y)\in f^{-1}(O)\}=(f^{-1}(O))_n$. But $f^{-1}(O)$ is measurable in $\textbf{Z}$ and therefore, from part I, we infer that $(f^{-1}(O))_n$ is measurable in $\textbf{Y}$.

$(\Leftarrow)$  $f^{-1}(O)=\cup_{n=1}^\infty \{n\}\times f^{-1}_n(O)$. This is clearly in the sigma algebra, because each $\{n\}\times f^{-1}_n(O)\in \textbf{Z}$.

**Part IV:** $f$ is integrable with respect to $\pi$ if and only if the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_Y |f_n| d\nu<\infty$$

In this case, we have:

$$\int_Z f d\pi = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_Y f d\nu =\int_Y \sum_{n=1}^\infty f d\nu$$

**Proof:** We note that $f$ is integrable if and only if $|f|$ has a finite integral. But we have simple functions $\varphi_n$ which converge to $|f|$ almost everywhere from which it follows that:

$$\int|f|d\mu=\lim_m \int \varphi_m d\mu=\lim_m \int \sum_{j=1}^{J_m} x_j \chi_{E_{jm}} d\mu=\lim_m \left(\sum_{j=1}^{J_m}x_j\pi(E_{jm})\right)=\lim_m \left(\sum_{j=1}^{J_m} x_j \sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu((E_{jm})_n)\right)=\lim_m \left(\sum_{j=1}^{J_m} x_j \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int\chi_{(E_{jm})_n} d\nu\right)=\lim_m \left(\sum_{j=1}^{J_m} x_j \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int\chi_{E_{jm}}(n,\cdot) d\nu\right)=\lim_m\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int\sum_{j=1}^{J_m} x_j\chi_{E_{jm}}(n,\cdot) d\nu\right)$$

However, we have that $\sum_{j=1}^{J_m} x_j\chi_{E_{jm}}(n,\cdot)=\varphi_m(n,\cdot)\xrightarrow[]{m} |f(n,\cdot)|=|f_n(\cdot)|$ pointwise and monotonically. Therefore,by the monotone converge theorem, we have:
$$\int |f| d\pi =\lim_m\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int \varphi(n,\cdot) d\nu\right)= \sup_m \sup_l \sum_{n=1}^l \int\sum_{j=1}^{J_m} x_j\chi_{E_{jm}}(n,\cdot) d\nu =\sup_l \sup_m \sum_{n=1}^l \int\sum_{j=1}^{J_m} x_j\chi_{E_{jm}}(n,\cdot) d\nu =\sup_l \sum_{n=1}^l\int  |f_n| d\nu=\sum_{l=1}^\infty \int  |f_n| d\nu$$

The reason why we can exchange the supremums follows from this other [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/977773/1015934). Therefore, we have the condition we were looking for:

$$\int |f|d\pi<\infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int |f_n|d\nu<\infty\quad \text{because} \quad \int |f|d\pi= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int |f_n|d\nu $$

In this case, me may conclude using the same approximation by simple $\varphi_n^+\rightarrow f^+$ and also $\varphi_n^- \rightarrow f^-$ (and subsequently using the monotone convergence theorem to commute the series and the integration) that:

$$\int f^+d\pi=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \int f_n^+ d\nu= \int \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_n^+d\nu<\infty $$
$$ \int f^-d\pi=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \int f_n^- d\nu= \int \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_n^- d\nu<\infty$$

Subtracting these two equalities, we have the desired conditions.